# Changing default CSS styles of Swing using AppContext, which is deprecated. Alternatives?

Tags: java, css, swing, deprecation-warning

In my Swing app, I use AppContext to change default styles of some of the HTML tags that are used inside JLabels and similar components. For example, I use `new JLabel("<html><b>Bold</b> not bold")` in the code.

My app uses custom Look And Feel. This look and feel changes default foreground colors of the text, but this is not applied to the components using HTML inside their text.

I achieve this change of foreground colors for the components that use HTML using the following code inside my look and feel:

```
try {
    final Field keyField = HTMLEditorKit.class.getDeclaredField("DEFAULT_STYLES_KEY");
            keyField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object key = keyField.get(null);

    StyleSheet defaultStyles = (StyleSheet) AppContext.getAppContext().get(key);
    defaultStyles.addRule("[my custom LAF CSS rules]");

    AppContext.getAppContext().put(key, defaultStyles);
} catch (Throwable ignored) {
}
```

This does work as it should, but I am getting warnings about deprecation and the use of internal API when compiling. I am not sure if the support for sun.awt.AppContext was dropped in Java 9 or later (the project is currently on Java 8), but I would like to keep the app as compatible with later releases as possible.

So my question is if I can achieve what I did with the code above without the use of sun.awt.AppContext and without some heavy refactoring such as inlining styles directly in the HTML of all the components that use it.